# Instance creation order error in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker

Look at the order of creation of the instances of a of the phases of my game.

[image]

Notice that first obj_BolaAzul (blue circle/square) is created, then obj_BolaVermelha (red circle/square).

[image]

As you can see, this is not what happens in the game. The obj_BolaAzul even being created first, it is above of obj_BolaVermelha.

This is happening in all other phases and began to occur a few days ago. Could someone tell me in some global configuration that I have modified.

Comment: Use different `depth` for them. The creation order does not affect the drawing order.

Comment: Right. Now could you explain the change? Before it was a way, now it is seen in the question.